# Questions about parameters used in Vision Transformer

Tags: deep-learning, vision-transformer

In the Vision Transformer (ViT), one splits the initial image into patches, with the initial paper (An Image is Worth 16x16 Words, found here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.11929) having patch size NxN=16x16.

I was wondering then, is there

1. A minimum number of N, related to the patch size?
2. A minimum number of patches, given an image of size M? The number of patches is given by the image size divided by the patch size.
3. A rough estimate of the minimum required number of pixels to be able to make an accurate prediction?

I tried finding academic papers that discuss such things (essentially, the variation in performance of a ViT when we change the above parameters) but I couldn't find any (although I'm sure they exist). If anybody could point to specific references that either answer the above questions or just study them, it'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The transformer-encoder part is similar to Bert, which was well explained here:  [How is the number of parameters be calculated in BERT model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64485777/how-is-the-number-of-parameters-be-calculated-in-bert-model)

ViT-Base looks quite simlar, 12 layers 12 heads 768 hidden. There are then extra parameters for patch embedding and MLP head. I can't make the numbers add up to 86M, so I'm not sure what is different, but it's a start :-)